# Sed path to file with variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed, path

I have in bash `sed -i 's|'$fileWithPath'|HAHA|g' /home/${user}.sql` when i put a variable in to the path it send me  no such file or directory but when i remove the variable and put a name it's working

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s|$fileWithPath|HAHA|g" /home/${user}.sql
```

use double quote to let shell variable get expanded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$fileWithPath` and `/home/${user}.sql` inside double quotes for shell expansion as well as making sure potential presence of spaces in `$user` variable are also not interpreted as different arguments to sed command:

```
sed -i "s|$fileWithPath|HAHA|g" "/home/${user}.sql"
```

Comment: is not working when I add quotes each time it tells me " wrong file or directory", only when I remove the variable from the path is good. I forgot to mention that it is a csv file

Comment: can you echo "$fileWithPath" and "${user}" and show its values.